# KDE's "global menu" widget usability

Tags: kde, gui, widgets

Why do toolbars of some programs like `Firefox` get showed up in the `Global menu` of KDE and some like `GIMP` do not?(Also I had a similar experience in unity DE)
I want to know the programmatic difference in terms of the tools present in toolkits like Qt or Gtk.
I'm using Kubuntu 18.04 with KDE 5.44.
Thanks.

Comment: Please mention the version and name of your distro. Also, your second paragraph would appear to be too broad in scope.

Comment: It's possible that the global menu works with (some) gtk3 applications like Firefox and doesn't work with (some) gtk2 applications like GIMP.

Comment: Maybe.But how does DE prevent the toolbar from being rendered in the window area to draw it somewhere else?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.